# Does pip check version label?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to use pip to install my own package from a local folder. I added a `find-links` option with that local folder in my pip.ini and I am saving my wheel in this folder.

- If the version of the wheel is `0.2.0`, that works.
- If the version is `0.2.0dev0`, that works.
- If the version is `0.2.0internal`, I have the following error:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement myownpackage (from versions: 0.2.0internal)
No matching distribution found for myownpackage`

pip seems to see the `0.2.0internal` version but he doesn't want it, why?

(pip 9.0.1, python 2.7.13, Windows 10)

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of research, I found this in [PEP440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/):

> The canonical public version identifiers MUST comply with the
>   following scheme:
>
> `[N!]N(.N)*[{a|b|rc}N][.postN][.devN]`
>
> Public version identifiers MUST
>   NOT include leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> Public version identifiers MUST be unique within a given distribution.
>
> Installation tools SHOULD ignore any public versions which do not
>   comply with this scheme but MUST also include the normalizations
>   specified below. Installation tools MAY warn the user when
>   non-compliant or ambiguous versions are detected.

I assume pip ignores my version because it does not comply with the scheme.